# Is there a way to make @SpringBootTest classes recursive?

Tags: java, spring, testing

Oftentimes I run an integration test and I want to specify just the class under test, and not worry about the multitude of dependencies like in the following example.

The serivce I want to test

```java
@Service
class MyService {
  private final SerivceA serviceA;

  public MyService(ServiceA serviceA) {
    this.serviceA = serviceA;
  }

  public void doThings() {
    serviceA.doOtherThings();
  }
}
```

How I write tests currently

```java
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.NONE,
    classes = {
      ServiceA.class,
      MyService.class
    })
```

What I would like to do

```java
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.NONE,
    classes = {
      MyService.class // recursively look for all dependencies (including ServiceA.class)
    })
```

Is there a way I can make the classes parameter recursive, so that I only need to include the class under test?

Comment: @ComponentScan(yourpackagename)

Comment: I don't think spring boot test is picking up @ComponentScan when it runs tests

Comment: Why not give it a try first ?

Comment: By default you don't need to specify any services in SpringBootTest as it loads everything under the application package into the test context. Do you use any other annotations on your test classes?

Comment: @ComponentScan does not load components during tests, using Spring Boot 2.2.3